# Is unlawful entry into Mexico a crime?

Tags: immigration, mexico

In the U.S. there is a federal law making unauthorized entry into the country illegal. Does Mexico have similar law?

If so, does anyone know of English translations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Short Answer

> Is unlawful entry into Mexico a crime?
>
> In the U.S. there is a federal law making unauthorized entry into the
> country illegal. Does Mexico have similar law?

Yes. Illegal entry into Mexico is illegal but, it is not a crime.

The form of the question suggest that the person asking it may not be familiar with the distinction between something being "[illegal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/illegal)" and something being a "[crime](https://www.lectlaw.com/def/c330.htm)". The notion that they are the same is a common misconception.

> If so, does anyone know of English translations?

An English translation of Mexico's immigration law can be found [here](https://www.albany.edu/%7Erk289758/documents/Ley_de_Migracion_en_Ingles.pdf).

## Long Answer

Illegal entry into Mexico is illegal and has legally authorized consequences, although it is not a crime.

#### Civil Consequences For Immigration Law Violations In Mexico

Civil detention of unlawful entrants into Mexico is authorized by Articles 99-105 of Mexico's [Migration Act of 2011](https://www.albany.edu/%7Erk289758/documents/Ley_de_Migracion_en_Ingles.pdf).

Deportation is authorized by Articles 114-125.

There are civil fines for violating immigration laws in Mexico based on a multiple of the minimum wage, ranging from 20 days of minimum wage to 10,000 days of minimum wage, depending upon the offense and its severity (one day's minimum wage is [88.36 pesos](https://tradingeconomics.com/mexico/minimum-wages)). Articles 143-158. So fines range from 1767.2 pesos to 883,600 pesos for immigration violations. [Today's exchange rate](https://www.currency-calc.com/USD_MXN) is 19.4 pesos to $1. So, these fines range from $91 USD to $45,546 USD.

#### Immigration Related Crimes In Mexico

Immigration crimes are found at Articles 159-162. According to the linked translation, these crimes are as follows:

> Article 159. A term of eight to 16 years in prison and a fine ranging
> from 5,000 to 15,000 days of the general minimum wage in effect in the
> Federal District will be imposed upon an individual who:
>
> I. Traffics one or more individuals in order to enter another country
> without the corresponding documentation and for the purpose of
> directly or indirectly obtaining a profit;
>
> II. Introduces one or more foreigners into Mexico without the
> corresponding documentation and for the purpose of directly or
> indirectly obtaining a profit; or
>
> III. Lodges or transports one or more foreigners in or through Mexico
> for the purpose of avoiding migratory inspection and in order to
> directly or indirectly obtain a profit.
>
> In order to actualize the crime provided for in this article, it will
> be necessary to
>
> demonstrate that the offender's intent is to obtain an indisputable,
> current, or impending economic benefit in cash or in kind.
>
> Penalties will not be imposed upon individuals of renowned moral
> rectitude who, for strictly humanitarian reasons and without seeking
> any benefit, assist an individual who has entered the country in an
> unlawful manner, even when such individuals [of renowned moral
> rectitude] receive donations or resources for continuing their
> humanitarian work.
>
> Article 160. The penalties indicated in the foregoing article will be
> doubled when the aforementioned conducts are carried out:
>
> I. With respect to children and adolescents, or when a child or
> adolescent who is not able to comprehend the significance of the
> action is induced to, motivated to, assisted in, or obligated to
> conduct any of the behaviors described in the previous article;
>
> II. Under conditions or using means that place or could place health,
> integrity, safety, or life at risk or that allow for inhumane or
> degrading treatment of the individuals affected by such conduct; or
>
> III. When the perpetrator or orchestrator is a public servant.
>
> Article 161. A public servant who assists, conceals, or prompts any
> person to violate the provisions of this Law in order to obtain a
> direct or indirect profit in cash or in kind will be sentenced to a
> term of four to eight years in prison and a fine ranging from 500 to
> 1,000 days of the general minimum wage in effect in the Federal
> District.
>
> Article 162. In regard to the crimes indicated in this Law, the
> Federal Office of the Public Prosecutor will exercise the criminal
> action on its own initiative. The Institute is obligated to provide
> the Federal Office of the Public Prosecutor with all elements
> necessary for prosecuting these crimes.

So basically, the only immigration crimes in Mexico are human trafficking and immigration related bribery. Illegal entry into Mexico, *per se*, even if it is intentional, while it is illegal and may justify civil immigration detention, deportation and/or a civil fine, is not a crime.

Of course, one could conceivably commit other crimes in connection with the immigration process (e.g. assaulting a government official, forging official documents), but illegal entry into Mexico, *per se* is never a crime, unlike the situation in U.S. immigration law, where illegal entry is both illegal and also a crime in many (but not all) circumstances.

Comment: Hust the sort of facts I was looking for.   Thank you for clarify the distinction you are drawing between something being illegal and crime.   In the U.S. I gather it is both, but not in Mexico.

Comment: "In the U.S. I gather it is both, but not in Mexico." Correct.

Comment: To add, I believe it was in 2011 that illegal entry to Mexico [was decriminalized](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/may/28/world/la-fg-mexico-migrants-20110528).